# replacement valid UK visit visa to a new passport because the old passport lost

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, passport-renewals

i am looking to replace my UK visit visa from lost passport to a new passport
it is valid visa , I have copy of it and it had been used for entry UK before
what is the procedure ?
it was issued in UAE Abu Dhabi via VFS in 2017

Comment: Where are you now? Is your lost visa a long-term Visit Visa (multiple entry)? When does it expire? Do you have a police report for the lost passport?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to apply for a replacement visa and show evidence of the loss.

> **[2. ECB17.2 Replacing a visa (or leave) where this has been lost or stolen (excluding 30 day short validity (travel) vignettes)](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/transferring-a-visa-to-a-new-passport-ecb17/transferring-a-visa-ecb17)**
>
> If the applicant loses their passport and visa, or has their passport and visa stolen, they are applying for a replacement using transfer of conditions. There will be a vignette transfer fee for the service. (See the [visa fees](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/aboutus/fees) page on GOV.UK for the current fee.)
>
> You will need to see a police report or other evidence that satisfactorily establishes that the passport is no longer in their possession. This also applies if an applicant had ‘leave to remain’ granted in the UK (excluding on a BRP) and is now applying to have it replaced overseas. See [Biometric information: case working](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/biometric-information) for further information on replacing a BRP lost overseas.
>
> If required, you may ask for supporting documentation to establish that their circumstances have not changed. ECOs should use i-search to obtain information on an applicant’s leave granted in the UK. If information is not available on i-search you must make a referral to Evidence and Enquiry Unit.