# Passport Lost with Valid UK Visa - Applied for a New Visa

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, lost-documents

I was issued with a standard visitor visa (Business Visit Visa Category) which was multiple entries and was valid for 6 Months.

Unfortunately, I lost my passport in London (I live in Pakistan and was in London to attend the conference). I reported my loss to Met police where they provided me with the reference number only and no paper report, then to get the emergency travel paper I reported that loss on ReportMyLoss.

I didn't overstay and returned to Pakistan as per my planned dates. On my return, I filed that incident to my local police station to be sure that I don't get into any trouble.

Now I just applied for a new Business visit visa. Had I not lost my passport, my current travel plans should have been covered by the validity dates in my previously issued visa. I believe this will support my case.

I sent all documents I had including Oyster card slip, Local Police Report, ReportMyLoss Report and photocopies of previous visa and passport and other supporting documents.

Did I follow the right steps? What possible issue ECO can highlight to reject my application?

Comment: It seems you reported the loss to the best of your ability. Don’t worry. UK will know when you left the country from the airline. The only thing I think you overlooked was that you should have notified the UK embassy when you returned to Pakistan so they could void that visa. I think you should be fine. Unfortunately  Nobody can tell you your chances, we’re not lottery analysts or psychic however I **think** you followed the right steps.

Comment: Duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121595/replacement-valid-uk-visit-visa-to-a-new-passport-because-the-old-passport-lost

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did sent an email to UKVI (Paid Email) did let them know about this incident as well but yes I forgot to mention that in my cover letter. Also can you please remove the hold for this question.

Comment: You have to edit your question. Remove the **what do you are the chances that this will cause an issue for me?** part because it’s opinion based

Comment: removed the objected statement

Comment: Got the visa :)

Comment: I was confident you would be approved. Next year reapply USA.