# UK Tier 4 Student Visa - Empty Envelope Returned

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, us-citizens, lost-documents

I am in a bit of a bind with my UK Tier4 Student Visa and I am looking for some advice or if anyone has gone through something similar.

Today my UPS return package arrived that supposedly contained my US Passport & Visa Decision except the package was open on both sides and completely empty.

I have filed a claim with UPS but need to move forward as my flight is set to leave September 15th.

I have no idea if the visa was even approved- is this something I can find out? If so will I need to get a new passport and complete the application again or can I get the vignette transferred if it was indeed approved? Does anyone have experience with a vignette transfer?

Comment: While it's possible the passport with its UK vignette will be found in some corner somewhere, it may never be located. Thus, it doesn't seem prudent to wait. You should move forward now to replace the passport. This US State Department webpage https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/after/lost-stolen.html describes how one replaces a lost or stolen passport; various methods are available at various costs, depending on how quickly the new passport is to be issued.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replacement valid UK visit visa to a new passport because the old passport lost](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121595/replacement-valid-uk-visit-visa-to-a-new-passport-because-the-old-passport-lost)

Comment: Why did you accept this parcel when it was open already? It clearly sounds like your passport was stolen.

Comment: You should report this to the embassy and your local police. The first can help you, the second: you need their documents for further steps

Comment: @David i don't think it's a strict duplicate. The linked question covers this one only partially.

Answer (score 3):

There is an extremely high chance that your passport was stolen to be used for fraudulent purposes. Therefore you should [report your passport as stolen](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/after/lost-stolen.html) immediately following the instructions found on the linked US governmental webpage. You might have to go to the nearest police station to file a lost/stolen report. Then, you should [contact your nearest US embassy or consulate](https://www.usembassy.gov/) and request a new passport. Finally, once you obtain your new passport, you should get in touch with the UK visa services to get the status of your visa application, and possibly [request that the visa be transferred on the new passport](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/transferring-a-visa-to-a-new-passport-ecb17/transferring-a-visa-ecb17#ecb172-replacing-a-visa-or-leave-where-this-has-been-lost-or-stolen-excluding-30-day-short-validity-travel-vignettes). For more details about the visa transfer see [this dedicated question on our site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/121595/22140).

In the meantime follow up with the shipping company and make a claim. The content of the shipment was lost or stolen so you should be entitled to some form of compensation.